# Display characters of a variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I am doing a bash script and I want to display the characters of a variable ($VAR). What I want the script to do is (pseudo-code) :

```
String var = "Hello";
for (int i = 0; i < var.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(var.substring(i, i+1));
}
```

The size of the variable can change, one time it can be 5 characters and the next time 6 for example. 
Thank you for you help!
Michaël

Comment: Why are you using bash for this?

Comment: Because I have no choice, it was imposed on me.

Comment: Sounds like punishment - there's no tag for that ... yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a, hopefully quite close, translation.

```
var="Hello"
for (( i = 0; i < ${#var}; i++ ))
do
    echo ${var:i:1}
done
```

Illustrates a few bash concepts.

- `${#var}` gives the number of characters in variable `${var}`
- `${var:x:y}` gives a substring of characters of `${var}` starting at position `x`, length `y`

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach:

```
echo hello | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'
```